# Example of universal net not eventually constant

Tags: general-topology

I know that:

1. If $\phi$ is eventually constant then $\phi$ is an universal net.
2. A sequence $\phi$ is an universal net if and only if $\phi$ is eventually constant.

I want see an example of an universal net not eventually constant.

Comment: There is no explicit example; you cannot even prove they exist without the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of ultranets is coupled to the existence of ultrafilters. Without assuming a strong form of AC you cannot show that ultrafilters exist in ZF, so in particular no "explicit" example can exist (there only are existence proofs based on Zorn's lemma or some such non-constructive theorem that's based on AC).

With an ultrafilter you can construct a universal net, and conversely the set of tails of an ultranet generates an ultrafilter. So we have an example of one iff we have an example of the other. BTW don't fret too much on it, ultranets are of very limited interest and are rarely even mentioned or used in papers.